# Cordova on Android; getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie") returns only the last cookie not the rest.

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

in our Android platform in a Cordova project `getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")` only returns the last cookie from the response and not all the cookies as it does in the iOS platform.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
cache:false,
url: url,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

data: dotJSON,
success: function( data, textStatus, req ) {
    $.mobile.loading( 'hide', {
        textVisible: false,
        theme: 'a',
        html: ""
    });

    var header = req.getAllResponseHeaders();

    //console.log(header);
    console.log(req.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")); // this only prints the following
   // 'Set-Cookie: DIdN=[...]; path=/'

   [...]
});
```

In the iOS platform `console.log(req.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));` also prints an ASPXAUTH-cookie which we need to keep the session going with the server.

I've search both on SO, the PhoneGap Google group and the Cordova Issue Tracker and found people with the same issue as me but they are all unanswered.

Anyone got any ideas on what might go wrong on the Android-platform but not on the iOS-platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by sending the cookies in the response body as a string and then stored it in local storage as such:

`window.localStorage.setItem("Cookies", data);`

and then i set them in all my ajax-requests using

`beforeSend:setHeader`

```
function setHeader(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', window.localStorage.getItem("Cookies"));
}
```

Hope this will help anyone else out there with the same problem.